# How to perform some Rules Actions WHILE some condition is TRUE?

Tags: 7, rules

Using [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules), how can you perform a set of Rules Actions ***`WHILE`*** (`some condition` = `TRUE`)?

About that condition: I'm not talking here about a Rules Condition ... Instead I mean some sort of boolean expression that evaluates to either `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

Also, even though Rules has the concept of "[Lists and Loops](http://drupal.placeto.be/tutorial/lists-and-loops)" (for which you can typically iterate over each item of such list via a Rules Loop), that's not what my question is about either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware how to implement such WHILE-construction by only using [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules). However, if you also enable the [Conditional Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_conditional) module, you can implement such WHILE-construction.

#### Example

Consider this rule (in Rules export format):

```
{ "rules_execute_a_while_loop" : {
    "LABEL" : "Execute a while loop",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "rules_conditional" ],
    "ON" : { "node_insert" : [], "node_update" : [] },
    "IF" : [
      { "node_is_of_type" : { "node" : [ "node" ], "type" : { "value" : { "article" : "article" } } } },
      { "entity_has_field" : { "entity" : [ "node" ], "field" : "field_free_format_nr" } }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "drupal_message" : { "message" : "Value specified for \u0022Free format nr\u0022 is: [node:field-free-format-nr]" } },
      { "variable_add" : {
          "USING" : { "type" : "integer", "value" : "1" },
          "PROVIDE" : { "variable_added" : { "loop_counter" : "Loop counter" } }
        }
      },
      {
        "WHILE" : { "NOT data_is" : {
            "data" : [ "loop-counter" ],
            "op" : "\u003E",
            "value" : [ "node:field-free-format-nr" ]
          }
        },
        "DO" : [
          { "drupal_message" : { "message" : "Do your thing for \u0022loop_counter\u0022 value = [loop-counter:value]" } },
          { "data_calc" : {
              "USING" : { "input_1" : [ "loop-counter" ], "op" : "+", "input_2" : "1" },
              "PROVIDE" : { "result" : { "incremented_counter" : "Incremented counter" } }
            }
          },
          { "data_set" : { "data" : [ "loop-counter" ], "value" : [ "incremented-counter" ] } }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Some more details about this rule:

- Rules Events: After creating a new node, or after updating an existing node.
- Rules Conditions:

  - Content is of type "Article".
  - Entity has field, for field with machine name `field_free_format_nr` (which is of type `integer`).

The above Rules Events and/or Rules Conditions can be more or less anything (I just used some of the popular ones). The actual magic is in the Rules Actions:

- <kbd>Show a message on the site</kbd>, just for demo / testing purposes, to show the value enter for the `field_free_format_nr` field.
- <kbd>Add a variable</kbd>, with machine name `loop_counter`, and initial value `1`.
- <kbd>While: NOT Data comparison</kbd>, whereas the test is to check if NOT (`loop-counter` is greater than `[node:field-free-format-nr]`), in which case all of the below Rules Actions are performed:

  - <kbd>Show a message on the site</kbd>,  just for demo / testing purposes, to show a message like

  > Do your thing for "loop_counter" value = [loop-counter:value]

  - <kbd>Calculate a value</kbd>, to increment `loop_counter` with `1`, and (temporary) store the result in `incremented_counter`
  - <kbd>Set a data value</kbd>, to copy the value of `incremented_counter` in `loop_counter`

BTW, it could well be that the last 2 Rules Actions can be consolidates in a single one, though using 2 Rules Actions should be easier to understand what's happening.

#### Demo

With the above rule enabled, these are the messages shown if I create or update an article, and specify a value of `3` for the `field_free_format_nr` field:

```
Value specified for "Free format nr" is: 3
Do your thing for "loop_counter" value = 1
Do your thing for "loop_counter" value = 2
Do your thing for "loop_counter" value = 3
```